# A repository of optimization problems for educational purposes?

Tags: optimization, teaching

Is someone maintaining a repository of optimization problems for practice or homework problems?

I've been talking to a few people lately who are working on building links between academia and industry. It would be nice if it was easy to access a wide variety of optimization problems that could be used for educational purposes-- the definition of the problem, the data, and maybe some answers.

I know there are various sources like the Paul Williams book and [this previous question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/case-studies-and-real-problems-for-teaching-optimization-and-modelling).  But, I was curious if anyone was pulling all these sources together?

If no one has done this, this might be a good project and would benefit our community.

Comment: Largest collection I came across is http://www.hakank.org/

Comment: A moodle-based platform with many courses related to OR used by several universities https://moodle.caseine.org/?lang=en Some courses are open (many are in French)

Comment: Im in and want to contribute, maybe i can help create an easy optimization model

Answer (score 2):

- [MIPLIB](https://miplib.zib.de/) for MILP problems
- [QPLIB](https://qplib.zib.de/) for QP problems
- https://github.com/ekhoda/optimization_problem_libraries contains references to many other problem collections

those are not specially for teaching and already formulated but many are licensed so they could be used in teaching. It honestly depends on what you want to teach.